# Why doesn't FileExists(path) work when the searched file is in Programs (x86) folder?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, file-io

I am not sure why or what a work around could be, so basic thing I want to check if a specific .exe exist and if so continue else bring error message.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateBackup.Click
  Dim path As String = txtFirebirdPath.Text & "\gbak.exe"
  If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(path) Then
    ...
  Else
    ...
  End if
End Sub
```

*txtFirebirdPath is the name of a Textbox, where after a fodler selection, has the Selected Path as Text.

While the gbak.exe is indeed there my programm tells me its not I have tried what if its on my desktop and it can find it no problem, so as in every other path just not when it includes pragramms (x86), why ?

Full forms Code:
https://github.com/20Peety02/stackoverflow_issue
*The issue is at line 145*

Comment: Have you set break points and stepped through your code to see where it's really going and what the variable values are?

Comment: Impossible to tell since your code is not a [mcve]. However, the path is not spelled “programms (x86)“. Fix the spelling and try again.

Comment: yup, I did as much as I could the Test enviroment is not on my work pc so I have to build a release and upload that then, however for test sakes I did get the the files to my pc and debugged it and as said it works fine as long the path is not going into the Programms (x86) folder

Comment: @KonradRudolph my spelling here dont matter as its not hard coded the path is selected via a folderDialog and the result palced in a textbox so the path  then comes from the systm itself,

Comment: @KonradRudolph I did Simplyfy the code / explanied the variable so the basic of my problem can be reproduced,

Comment: Is there a backslash at the end of `txtFirebirdPath.Text`? If so, you should remove the one in `"\gbak.exe"`

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville Or still better, don't build paths using string concatenation, build them using `System.IO.Path.Combine`.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville from the output I get yes to the backslash however I am going to try out if its because of it maybe it has a problem with "\" beeing the first of the string.
(also yes as the varible only has a folder path not the file I am then searching for )

Comment: @Craig did tried it with path.combine but I may also have used it wrong so I wil try that again, thanks

Comment: Ok so weird, but maybe the problem idk why but when I set a breakpoint and debug it it does go into the if which means that fileExist is true so it does work when debugging just not in one go does it handle anything to fast, is taht a possible reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.
Shows if the file exists or not.

```
Public Class Form1

   Dim selectedfoldername As String = Nothing
   Dim specifiedfilename As String = Nothing

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      '
      FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
      selectedfoldername = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
      MsgBox("The filepath " & selectedfoldername & " was selected.")
      '
   End Sub

   Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
      '
      specifiedfilename = Trim(TextBox1.Text)
      '
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
      '
      If Trim(selectedfoldername) <> "" Then
         If Trim(specifiedfilename) <> "" Then
            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(selectedfoldername & "\" & specifiedfilename) Then
               MsgBox("File Exists: " & selectedfoldername & "\" & specifiedfilename & " exists already")
            Else
               MsgBox("File Not Found: " & selectedfoldername & "\" & specifiedfilename & " does not exist")
            End If
         Else
            MsgBox("No filename specified")
         End If
      Else
         MsgBox("No folder selected")
      End If
      '
   End Sub

End Class
```

Maybe your issue lies elsewhere, and you need to check the rest of your code.

[image]

Comment: I will check the rest of my code f I cant find it I will probably provide it so others can check over it as well

Comment: Could it be that my program doesnt has the right to Access the file and so gets a false state ? ok nvm when on launchign my program as admin doesnt do it either

Comment: I'm not sure about your personal pc, but usually windows prompts for permission to access the folder when writing files to it. I dont think the permission is required when reading files. And also, I've never come across files in the root of the Programs FIles / Program Files (x86) folders,  those folders usualyy contain other folders (but never a file in the root)... I pasted a notepad/text file in the program files (x86) folder  to test the file exists method/statements.  Yes maybe others, more knowledgable than myself could help pinpoint the cause...

Comment: oh sorry if that came across like I am looking for a file in the root folder, no the path is c:\programs (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_3_0_0\gbak.exe

Answer (score 0):

The string you are passing to `My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists` probably has two backslashes (in a row) so it will return False:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\\gbak.exe`

Take a look at [`System.IO.Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-7.0) as Craig suggested, this function will return a properly built path.

Comment: '''
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "gbak.exe")) Then
...
End if
'''
does not work either, path is a string varible and "gbak.exe" is fixed

Comment: I uploaded the full Options forms on github 
<https://github.com/20Peety02/stackoverflow_issue>

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER WAS:
the Issue was what @Zeddy pointed out before I checked at the wrong place, it was the process arguments I guve to the gbak.exe to be executed since I had only one catch exception it would always drop into the not found msg... thats my bad I corrected the syntax it does work now as intended, thanks for everyones hellp!